# something wrong with onmousemove

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to write script on my button. I don't know what's wrong in my code.but, when I tried to wrote it on codepen it works perfectly as my expected. I wrote it on vscode before but caught an error.

I tried to recreated it in external js, but didn't work either

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
      btn.onmousemove = function (e) {
        const x = e.pageX - btn.offsetLeft;
        const y = e.pageY - btn.offsetTop;

        btn.style.setProperty('--x', x + 'px');
        btn.style.setProperty('--y', y + 'px');
      };
```

```css
.btn {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  background-color: #363636;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.btn span {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.btn::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: var(--y);
  left: var(--x);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #2196f3;
  transition: width 0.6s, height 0.6s;
}

.btn:hover::before {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn"><span>Button</span></a>
```

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'onmousemove')
        at js.js:2:23
```

Comment: why it works only on snippet??? but not on browser :(((

Comment: Please post the complete code exactly as you have it in the file(s) in vscode, and then it will be easier to diagnose the issue.

Comment: @JD_dev It doesn't show up? I already post the complete file :(

Comment: It Works on the browser you just need to review the code in your file.

Comment: You have only the code in the post in an HTML file without any other code or structure? And is it in the same order that appears in the post (i.e. JS, CSS, HTML). The code runs fine if it's in a properly structured HTML file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is telling you that the element you are trying to change the properties of is null. The reason for this is that your JavaScript code executes before your HTML element loads in.

Wrap your code in a window.onload function and it should work as intended.

```
window.onload = function(){ 
    // rest of code
};
```

Alternatively, you can also try adding the "defer" attribute to your script tag in HTML.

```
<script src="script.js" defer></script>
```

Comment: Thank youuu soo muchhhhh. it workssss adding deferrrrr